# Inherited class variables when initialized are overriding own value setted by parent

Tags: java, android, inheritance, constructor, parent

I have in my app something like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    public A (){
        init();
    }
    
    protected abstract void init();
}

public class B extends A {

    private String strName = "";

    public B (){
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void init(){
        strName = "Hello";
    }
}
```

I'm creating an instance of class B. And the app is running this order:

1- Constructor B, calls the super

2- Constructor A, calls init() function

3- Init() overriden in B is assigning "Hello" to strName variable

4- Then the attributes in class B are initialized, and the current value "Hello" is overwritten by the initialize value "";

Which is the correct structure if I want a common method in many childrens like init(), to be called in the parent. To avoid repeating it in every child. And avoiding the issue that I'm having. Or maybe the init() function in the parent should be called in the child constructor below the super.

Comment: You should avoid calling overridable methods in your constructor. It leads to confusing effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is `super()` calls the parent constructor, which calls init(). The `strName = "";` statement is then run inside the child class constructor after the `super()` call.

`strName` should be a `protected` variable in the parent class if you want to set it up like that. Otherwise, you should just bite the bullet and manually initialize it in the constructor after the call to `super();` That's the safest and most predictable way to do this.

Comment: Yep. And having protected fields is most of the time: not a good design. So, rather keep the field in the subclasses, and make them final, and init them in the ctor.

Comment: So: 1. call super; 2. do all field initialisations ... = ...; 3. do rest of constructor